# Pelargonium rapidly losing leaves after sunburn

Tags: flowers, sunlight

Timeline:

1. Was very healthy despite the tiny container.
2. **Possibly** got in contact with other pelargoniums exhibiting some probably fungal disease.
3. Was still completely healthy.
4. Was moved outdoors at direct sun with temperatures reaching 35°C in the shade some days.
5. Developed the symptoms 2 weeks later, was moved indoors another week later.
6. Two months passed since. This is how it looks now and is still losing leaves although some new growth is also observed. Is it doomed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

The **outcome** and why Bamboo's answer is marked as accepted:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be fine, just  cut it back to healthy growth if you want to keep it indoors over winter, or if you feel uncomfortable cutting it back that far, just cut off the damaged growth. It will have been heat that caused this, and possibly insufficient water. I'm in the UK and later in September,I cut mine right back to about 2 or 3 inches and overwinter them in a cool but not frosty place,out of the rain, then tidy them up in spring, repot in fresh potting soil indoors and put them back outdoors when overnight frosts have  more or less stopped.

Comment: I hope I remember to accept this answer in several months when everything is fine. To digress, do You think `cutting back` is important? That's a huge topic but let's focus on the situation at hand.

Comment: Yes, it is important - your plant already has leggy, stems, but the really important thing is, when to cut it back - what do you do with it in winter? Will you be bringing it  indoors and letting it grow indoors, or just keeping  it somewhere unheated but frost free till spring?

Answer (score 0):

#4 may be the key issue here.

I have the same problem with mine, as the summers are hot and the sun is harsh. At nurseries, they grow very well because they are under a shade cloth, providing around 50% shade protection. The symptoms I had on mine are just the same: dead leaves and even the stems turn yellow.

These may be tender hybrids which are not as tough as the larger zonal Pelargoniums. Ask the nursery team what level of shading cloth you need, or put them in a position where they get only morning sun, and are in shade before noon.

To rule-out fungal (or other pathogen) infection, keep them isolated. See if the new leaves develop the same symptoms as they grow. The new growth looks healthy, but keep watching it. If you find the new location suits them and they no longer exhibit any necrotic lesions, you may start new plants from cuttings.